# Can't set Atheros AR9485 to master mode

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I'm using an Atheros AR9485 wireless NIC on an old acer notebook.

Here's the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux PC 4.15.0-101-generic #102~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 11:38:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's displayed as `wlp7s0` in `ifconfig`.

Here's the output of `ethtool -i wlp7s0`:

```
driver: ath9k
version: 4.15.0-101-generic
firmware-version: N/A
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:07:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

And I'm getting the following error if I try to set it to master mode:

```
root@PC:~# iwconfig wlp7s0 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlp7s0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Even though `iw wlp7s0` shows that it is supported:

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
     * mesh point
     * P2P-client
     * P2P-GO
     * Unknown mode (11)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks